# image pushing unordered list down

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: what i am getting]

But I'm getting this:

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="quicklinks-main">
<li>Quick Access to Your Pharmacy Needs:</li>
<img id="refillBttle" src="images/prescription-refill-bottle.png" alt="prescription pills" />
<li><a id="quicklinks-refill-icon" href="#">Prescription Refills</a></li>
<li><a id="quicklinks-drug-center-icon" href="#"><span>Drug Information Center</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When I add the image it pushes the rest of the list down and messes it up. How can I correct this?

Comment: We really need a) a link to the live site, or a broken fiddle and b) some CSS. Also put the image in a `li` tag

Comment: damn image tag isn't working! how can i add images - i selected images and it doesn't seem to wanna work?

Comment: I would recommend making that image a `background-image`.

Comment: Also, adding that image tag inside the `UL` is invalid HTML.

Comment: doing that - it squishes the image to the size of the list item

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the img inside a new li

You can see an example here:
http://www.cvs.com/

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/SXMjm/ . Based on the CSS  and HTML of that site I added "overflow: visible; height:52px;" to the ul and the img inside li-s with the proper classes + this css "width: 0px;position: relative;".